# Why to use rtrim()?

Tags: php

I have downloaded some PHP code because I want to modify it and use it for my project.
I have this line of code:

```
$uri=rtrim(dirname($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']),'/\\');
```

I know the $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] it is a superglobal variable that returns the file name of the current running script.

But I do not know why rtrim is used!
 Can someone shortly explain to me?

Comment: It seems the programmer intention was to avoid problems, if the given directory contains an ending '\' or an ending '/'.

Comment: So the function rtrim() removes the '\' or\and the '/' characters?

Comment: No, obviously you can tell the rtrim function the list of characters to be removed as second parameter. It´s running that way in different programming languages. You could also start using google: "rtrim php" and you would have found the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the PHP [doc](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.rtrim.php):

> rtrim — Strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a
>   string

To explain more :

**_SERVER['PHP_SELF']:**
 *will return The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root. For instance, `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` in a script at the address http://example.com/foo/bar.php would be **/foo/bar.php***

And the **dirname** will Returns a parent directory's path like **src/foo/bar.php**.

To ensure that there is no special caracter inside , the rtrim will strip whitespace (or other characters) from the end of a string.

Hope this help you.